# Prevent iOS from adding words to dictionary that are entered in a UITextField?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone keyboard security,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955010/iphone-keyboard-security)

I've been wondering about the following: if I type an unknown word often enough on iOS, at some point (I think it's after the third input) it will add the word to its internal dictionary (Google for "dynamic-text.dat" for further information).

However what about the `UITextFields` I'm using inside my app? What if I don't want iOS to learn what is entered there (because it is sensitive data)? Is it enough to disable auto correction on the field?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1955010/558933

Comment: Well, maybe no more. At least in the Simulator I can see no dynamic-text.dat any longer. Instead there are two Sqlite databases. So new behavior maybe?

Comment: Okay, my bad. The file is there. I was in the wrong folder. There are two "Keyboard" folders. One is under "User".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a test program with three `UITextFields`. First one has auto correction YES, second one has NO and the third one has no explicit setting but is set to be secure (password).

Observing dynamic-text.dat in ~Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Library/Keyboard/dynamic-text.dat I can see that after typing a word two times and exiting the app via home button, writes the words into the file for all non-secure fields.

This means: words will be stored in dynamic-text.dat *even* if autocorrection is set to NO on a UITextField! Secure fields however never write to the file.

My test was done with iOS 5.1 and the iPhone Simulator.

Comment: Confirmed these tests. Data is leaked on iOS 5.1 and iOS 6.0.

Comment: The issue has been reported to Apple as bug 12077737. I got feedback that it is under investigation but no visible action. Have you also tried previous iOS versions? I suppose it did not leak there.

Comment: Thanks for filing bug, Krumelur. Did not try on previous iOS versions. I'm thinking most users are using 5.1 and 6.0 today, so this represents a problem for lots of people.

Comment: But good to hear that you also see it as an issue.